# Not same behavior of Make in Windows as on Linux, how to compile simple C++11 code with Make on Windows?

Tags: c++11, gcc, visual-studio-code, makefile, codeblocks

I have started to study C++ and previously compiled with make in Linux. Now I'm trying to use **VS Cod**e in Windows with the Codeblocks GCC package installed and added the appropriate path to the **PATH** variable. I am using a **C++11** feature **Foreach** and I need to specify this in the compiler call. I want to run ***make code*** and have it compiled adequately with the standard used. I have this functionality in Linux but here in Windows is behaving differently.

**code.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void)  {
    using namespace std;
    for (short i : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

}
```

EDIT

When I'm Linux I can do the command `make code` and it compiles with the appropriate flags for the source code. Meaning, it embeds the --std=c++11 flag by itself. But in Windows with no **makefile** it asks for a make file

```
$g++ --version
$g++.exe (tdm-1) 5.1.0
```

I'm doing this on Windows which works on Linux:

```
$make code
$Error: can't read makefile 'makefile'
```

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? What flags are you giving to `g++` when building?

Comment: show your `makefile`. What errors do you get?

Comment: What does "behaving differently" mean?  There's no way for us to respond if you don't state a problem and ask a question.

Comment: Updated with info, Ty for the help

Comment: @CarlosCheco: Just to check, you have **no** makefile on Linux either? You just use the default `make` rules there?

Comment: @MSalters Positive on that

Comment: What make version are you using, because it works for me just fine on Windows: `$ make code` -> `g++ -std=c++11    code.cpp   -o code`

Comment: @ssbssa I'm trying out between Codeblocks and MinGW binaries. Which version do you have?

Comment: I have make 4.3 of MSYS2.